# JSP include - compilation error cannot find symbol

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, jspinclude

Hi (my first question on stackoverflow),

I'm using JSP on my website and I've got an error when I try to deploy it.

For information, my website is hosted by Google App Engine. Locally, everything is working good.

The way I include jsp from an other jsp.

**index.jsp**

```
<% Lang lang = (Lang)request.getAttribute("lang"); %>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="<%= lang.toString() %>">
...
<%@ include file="notFound.jsp" %>
```

in **notFound.jsp**, locally I'm using lang without any declaration. Exemple:

```
<h1><%=Resource.NOTFOUND_title1.get(lang) %></h1>
```

BUT, when I try to deploy on my GAE project, I've errors like this (after jsp compilation):

> /tmp/1511964097028-0/org/apache/jsp/notFound_jsp.java:112: error:
>   cannot find symbol out.print(Resource.NOTFOUND_title1.get(lang) );

I find out same errors after a google research but solutions didn't work for my case...
I've tried to declare lang again but I've got an error due to an already declared variable.... I've tried to use global variable, but ! symbol is not recognized...

Please, help me :)